# Multiple Single Html Pages Sails.js

Tags: node.js, static, assets, sails.js

I have a lot of landings in my application, where in index page I have to change some parameters in hrefs according to users GET query. 
So, in views folder i have a lot different **./pattterns/pattern1/index.ejs** for each single web page and in assets folder 
I have **./patterns/pattern1/static-css-and-img-and-etc**.

Now, the problem is I need to fix all links from pattern1/index.ejs to this static files, because **by default static is searched in /assets/** and I can't figre out how to point in every other rending of view to specific **/assets/patterns/pattern1/** folder to fetch static from.

Any suggestions would be appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the "layout"-setting in the render-call:

```
 var templatetype = "patterns/pattern1/";

 data = {
    ....
    layout: templatetype + "index.ejs"
 };

 res.view(templatetype +"mysite",data);
```

In this example SailsJS is looking for "patterns/pattern1/index.ejs" and render this with "patterns/pattern1/mysite.ejs"

Comment: Thank you so much for this advice, but it didn't worked the way I expected(
I moved the index.ejs file this way:
return res.view('../assets/prls/med_g/index.ejs', {
            layout: false,
            cpaLink: 'http://google.com'
        });

But it still tries to find pages in '/assets' at first, and do not search at the '/assets/pattern' as I wish